# How to set a variable for JavaScript function to embed a video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a grid like this:

```
<div class="main">
    <ul id="og-grid" class="og-grid">
        <li>
            <a href="http://..." data-video="my-url"  data-largesrc="images/1.jpg" data-title="Title" data-description="Description">
                <img src="images/thumbs/1.jpg" alt="img01"/>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The **data-video** parameter is a url, in JavaScript I don't know how to create this function appropriately:

```
Preview.prototype = {
 create : function() {
    this.$title = $( '<h3></h3>' );
    this.$description = $( '<p></p>' );     
    this.$href = $( '<a href="#">Visit website</a>' );
    this.$details = $( '<div class="og-details"></div>' ).append( this.$title, this.$description, this.$href );
    this.$loading = $( '<div class="og-loading"></div>' );
    this.$fullimage = $( '<div class="og-fullimg"></div>' ).append( this.$loading );            
    this.$videosrc = $( '<iframe class="og-video" width="560" height="315" src="data-video" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>' ).append( this.$loading );
    this.$closePreview = $( '<span class="og-close"></span>' );
    this.$previewInner = $( '<div class="og-expander-inner"></div>' ).append( this.$closePreview, this.$videosrc, this.$details );
    this.$previewEl = $( '<div class="og-expander"></div>' ).append( this.$previewInner );
    this.$item.append( this.getEl() );
    if( support ) {
        this.setTransition();
    }
}
```

How could I call the data-video url of my html file inside the `this.$videosrc` of this JavaScript where `src` is declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery you could get the data-video value with something like this:

```
var video_src  = $('[data-video]').attr('data-video');
```

If you are using only JavaScript give the link a ID like video_1 and

```
var video_src = document.getElementById("video_1").getAttribute("data-video");
```

You would pass that into your Preview object either when you initialize the objects properties, or by setting it later in another method/function.

```
    this.$videosrc = $( '<iframe class="og-video" width="560" height="315" src='+ video_src +' frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>' ).append( this.$loading );
```

Answer (score 1):

You use the jquery `.data()` method:

```
this.$videosrc = $( '<iframe class="og-video" width="560" height="315" src="' + 
$(this.getEl()).data('video') + 
'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>')
.append( this.$loading );
```

If I'm understanding your method correctly, there's a `this.getEl()` method that returns a reference to the element where the data-video parameter is, and the code above should work if that's true.

Comment: Thanks, I tried but it gives me a null...on my html I wrote on `data-video="https://www.youtube.com/embed/an_id"` but the output gives me a totally different `src="http://mywebsite/null"`

Comment: `this.getEl()` doesn't do what I hoped it did, then... you need to get the reference to the element with your data-video parameter somehow before you can call `$(el).data('video')` to get the value.